# how to logout after getting authenticated by single sign on provider?

Tags: logout, rpxnow

I am trying to provide authentication facility through third party single sign on provider like rpxnow. After login on every refresh of page I am not able to retrieve the cookies set by the provider so that I can delete them when user desires to log out?
Is there any other way to gracefully logout the user without trying to search for cookies etc., or releasing the token provided by them after authentication?

Comment: looks like you're not the only one to ask... http://rpxwiki.com/Help#comment1244506971

Comment: true i saw there and came here !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a workaround. I stored the token retrieved from single sign on site and onclick of logout deleted the token. Every call handler for each page was initiated by checking for validating for token variable in session.